# compare Two field if the field is in the content of other field using javascript after submit button clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am not a javascript expert thats why I will really appreciate any advice

I have a textfield named try where in I will input something 
ex:

try value is

```
87
```

then I have another textfield named field11

field11 has a value of

```
777-a98;87-bx23;000-t88;245-k7
```

I wanted to compare try and field11 if try is found in the content of field 11 it will set the textfield named msg to 87-bx23 matched

msg value will be

```
87-bx23 matched
```

my code is like this but its not giving the desired output I know my comparison is wrong it just I dont know how

```
<script>
 $(document).ready( function(){

    $('#submit').click(function() {

if (document.getElementById('try').value != document.getElementById('field11').value)

{       
alert('dont match!');
$("#msg").val ("dont match!");

     }
    else if (document.getElementById('try').value == document.getElementById('field11').value) {

}alert(document.getElementById('try').value + " exists");
$("#msg").val(document.getElementById('try').value + " exists");

    });
});   
</script>
```

I also try this but if I input 77 it saying it exist even not

```
    <div id="requirement #2">

  <button type="button" id="button2" onclick="StringSearch()">Search</button>
</div>



<script>




        function StringSearch() {

      var SearchTerm = document.getElementById('try').value;
      var TextSearch = document.getElementById('field11').value;

      if (SearchTerm.length > 0 && TextSearch.indexOf(SearchTerm) > -1) {
        alert("Patient Exists");
      } else {
        alert("Patient Does not exist click add if you want to add the patient");

     $("#msg").val(document.getElementById('try').value + " exists");
        $("#t1").val("1");
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: will try only contain a number?

Comment: Use regex in javascript to compare. Don't use == and != because this will match for exact values. Just see this link: https://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html

Comment: As aside comment: store 'document.getElementById('try')' in a variable. That makes it easier and faster.

Comment: Also, store document.getElementById('field11').value as a variable. Generally, store everything you use more than once or twice as a variable for readability.

Comment: Why dont you check indexof ?

Comment: @Arshad consider this case: `777-a87;87-bx23;` `String.indexOf('87')` would incorrectly give the index the first 87, which is not what OP wanted to query for.

Comment: Hi thank you for all your help I updated the code tried both but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('field11').value.match(new RegExp("(" + "87" + "-[a-z0-9]+);"))[1])
```

The Generated Regex when `try value = 87`:

```
/(87-[a-z0-9]+);/
```

So what is this monstrosity? We generate a [Regex Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), that looks for the try value followed by a dash, and one or more characters from a-z or 1-9, followed by a semicolon. [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is used to determine an array of matches, the `array[1]` is the first capture group (the part of the RegEx between the brackets), which is in this case `87-bx23`

Comment: I tried to use it but if i type 77 it says exist which is not and I typed 245 but it says not exist but it does

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to rewrite your code to store variables for the elements and use a Regexp to do the search for the value:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
    var tryElem = document.getElementById('try');
    var field1 = document.getElementById('field11');

    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var regex = new Regexp(tryelem +'[^;]*');
        var match = regex.exec(field.value);
        if (match)
        {
            alert(match + " exists");
            $("#mag").val(match + " exists");
        }
        else
        {
            alert('dont match!');
            $("#msg").val ("dont match!");
        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

The code does more or less the same as yours, except for the regex:

```
tryelem +'[^;]*'
```

It builds a regular expression form the the value of tryElem and then it searches forward and matches up to the first semi colon (zero or more characters).

Now the match will contain: '87-bx23'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<input type="text" id="try"/>
<input type="text" id="field11" value="777-a98;87-bx23;000-t88;245-k7"/>
<input type="text" id="msg"/>
<input type="button" id="submit"/>
```

And js:

```
$(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
         var Try=$("#try").val(),
             f11=$("#field11").val(),
             msg=$("#msg");
         //but if you want search in number part only (before dash sign), uncomment line below and comment next line.
         //var r=((";"+f11+";").match(new RegExp(";([^;-]*"+Try+".*?-.+?);"))||[])[1];
          var r=((";"+f11+";").match(new RegExp(";([^;]*"+Try+"[^;]*);"))||[])[1];
          msg.val(r||"don't match!!");
    });
 });
```

You can check or change both of them [online](https://jsbin.com/lezejidalu/edit?output)